# custom permlink .htaccess file 404 Not Found error

Tags: permalinks, htaccess

i read alot of atricles taking about this but i could fix my problem yet .. i want to make the permlink custom

> /%category%/%postname%

and i searched for the .htaccess in the wordpress files and i couldn't find it so i created one and added this code

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sitename/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /sitename/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

in the RewriteBase this name is the name of the folder of wordpress in my hosting 
, when i open my site the permlink changed as i want but when i open the page it gives me an error 404 Not Found error  by the way i tried to choose the twentytwelve but its not working also , i added the .haccess file in the file mythemes in mytemplate  is that the right place ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Wordpress installation is in the folder 'sitename', than this .htaccess should go in that folder. Not your theme folder.

From the Wordpress codex: WordPress's index.php and .htaccess files should be together in the directory indicated by the Site address (URL) setting on your General Options page (http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks)

Comment: you mean directly in the folder not inside any othe folder ??

Comment: its working thaaaaaanks alot Vivienne :)

Comment: You're very welcome. You might want to accept my answer, so that this issue shows up as resolved ([Accepting Answers: How does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235))